# How to migrate from deprecated EmbeddedJMS to recommended EmbeddedActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis, spring-boot-starter

I have a Spring Boot app with an embedded queue. I'm using the `spring-boot-starter-artemis` dependency and trying to upgrade my Java app.

I could not find any guide, and a few things are not clear, e.g.:

**Checking if a queue exist**

EmbeddedJMS:

```java
jmsServer.getJMSServerManager().getBindingsOnQueue(queueName).length > 0
```

Can it be:

```java
jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().isAddressBound(queueName)
```

or maybe:

```java
jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().bindingQuery(SimpleString.toSimpleString(queueName)).isExists()
```

**Creation of queue:**

```java
jmsServer.getJMSServerManager().createQueue(true, queueName, null, true, queueName)
```

with params `(boolean storeConfig, String queueName, String selectorString, boolean durable, String... bindings)`

Is it the same like:

```java
QueueConfiguration queueConfiguration = new QueueConfiguration(queueName);
queueConfiguration.setDurable(true);
return jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().createQueue(queueConfiguration, true).isEnabled();
```

(added)
**Getting address:**

```java
jmsServer.getJMSServerManager().getAddressSettings(address);
```

is the same like:

```java
jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().getAddressSettingsRepository().getMatch(address);
```

**Not sure how migration Connection Factory settings**

```
final Configuration jmsConfiguration = new ConfigurationImpl();
jmsConfiguration.getConnectionFactoryConfigurations()
.add(new ConnectionFactoryConfigurationImpl()
.setName("cf")           
.setConnectorNames(Collections.singletonList("connector"))       
.setBindings("cf")); 
embeddedActiveMQ.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a queue exists I think the simplest equivalent solution would be:

```java
server.locateQueue("myQueue") != null
```

To create a queue the simplest equivalent solution would be:

```java
server.createQueue(new QueueConfiguration("myQueue")) != null
```

The queue will be durable by default so there's no reason use `setDurable(true)`.
To get address settings you use this (as you suspect):

```java
server.getAddressSettingsRepository().getMatch(address);
```

Regarding connection factories, you don't actually need to configure connection factories on the broker. You simply need to configure the properties for the `InitialContext` for your JNDI lookup. See [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html#jndi) for more details on that.