# How to send object in message with EmbeddedActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-artemis

This is another problem that found when migrating EmbeddedJMS to EmbeddedActiveMQ: [How to migrate from deprecated EmbeddedJMS to recommended EmbeddedActiveMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73583055/how-to-migrate-from-deprecated-embeddedjms-to-recommended-embeddedactivemq)

Previously to send message with object used

```java
try {
    producer.send(session.createObjectMessage(message));
    session.commit();
} catch (JMSException e) {
    log.error(e);
}
```

Where message object is just serializable.

With new approach those classes does not match and use this to produce message:

```java
try {
    final ClientMessage msg = clientSession.createMessage(true);
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
        oos.writeObject(message);
        oos.flush();
        msg.writeBodyBufferBytes(baos.toByteArray());
        clientProducer.send(msg);
        clientSession.commit();
    }
} catch(ActiveMQException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

To read it assumed that need to do it backwards like this:

```java
ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(clientMessage.getBodyBuffer().toByteBuffer().array());
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
try {
    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(arrayInputStream);
    objectInputStream.readObject();
} catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

However this does not work, there is exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 000000B2
```

Anything that I'm missing? Is there any more efficient/elegant way to do this?

Comment: Ditch that code and use a `JmsTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should continue to use your JMS Connections, Sessions, MessageConsumers, MessageProducers, etc. Just because you switch to `EmbeddedActiveMQ` doesn't mean you need to change any of your clients (aside from perhaps some JNDI-related code). JMS is still supported.

Aside from that I would strongly discourage you from using JMS `ObjectMessage`. They depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload. This process is generally considered unsafe, because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this which is why most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages. Aside from the security issues Java serialization is *slow*.

There are also a number of other issues with using JMS `ObjectMessage` not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/). This article has a good suggestion for how to replace `ObjectMessage` - define a data representation for the payload (JSON, protobuf, XML) and use `TextMessage` or `BytesMessage` to carry it.

Comment: Used this way because it was mentioned here: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html regarding JNDI I could not connect in way how it's described

Comment: The documentation you cited is just an example. It's not a specific recommendation that you change your JMS code to use the core API.

Comment: As far as JNDI goes you should probably create a new question about it. I can't help without more details about what you're doing and what's going wrong.