# Messages are not consumed when connection use JNDI or ActiveMQConnectionFactory to connect to EmbeddedActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-artemis

This is follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73635719/how-to-send-object-in-message-with-embeddedactivemq).

My code can initiate connection, session etc., however messages are not consumed. I don't see any exceptions in logs.

This test reproduces the problem:

```java
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.Context;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.QueueConfiguration;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.settings.impl.AddressSettings;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;

public class Test {

    EmbeddedActiveMQ jmsServer;

    final String QUEUE_NAME = "myQueue";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final String baseDir = File.separator + "tmp";
        final EmbeddedActiveMQ embeddedActiveMQ = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
        final Configuration config = new ConfigurationImpl();
        config.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        config.setBindingsDirectory(baseDir + File.separator + "bindings");
        config.setJournalDirectory(baseDir + File.separator + "journal");
        config.setPagingDirectory(baseDir + File.separator + "paging");
        config.setLargeMessagesDirectory(baseDir + File.separator + "largemessages");
        config.setSecurityEnabled(false);

        AddressSettings adr = new AddressSettings();
        adr.setDeadLetterAddress(new SimpleString("DLQ"));
        adr.setExpiryAddress(new SimpleString("ExpiryQueue"));
        config.addAddressSetting("#", adr);

        config.addAcceptorConfiguration("invmConnectionFactory", "vm://0");
        embeddedActiveMQ.setConfiguration(config);
        this.jmsServer = embeddedActiveMQ;
        this.jmsServer.start();

        System.out.println("creating queue");
        final boolean isSuccess = jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().createQueue(new QueueConfiguration(QUEUE_NAME)) != null;
        if(isSuccess) {
            System.out.println(QUEUE_NAME + "queue created");
        }

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        try {
            this.jmsServer.stop();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void simpleTest() throws Exception {

        Hashtable d = new Hashtable();
        d.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
        d.put("connectionFactory.invmConnectionFactory", "vm://0");
        final ActiveMQInitialContextFactory activeMQInitialContextFactory = new ActiveMQInitialContextFactory();
        Context initialContext = activeMQInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(d);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("invmConnectionFactory");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        consumer.setMessageListener(message -> {
            System.out.println("=== " + message);
            try {
                message.acknowledge();
                session.commit();
                latch.countDown();
            } catch(JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        connection.start();
        producer.send(session.createMessage());
        session.commit();
        if(!latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JustinBertram create instance of class that implements MessageListener

Comment: The code shared is working if you replace `consumer.setMessageListener(message -> System.out.println("onMessage: " + message));` and `producer.send(session.createObjectMessage("TEST"));`. This means the issue is on the message listener or on the message object.

Comment: @JustinBertram code that you prepared in test works, looks like issue with my application. If EmbeddedActiveMQ had been created in different project then had issue in production code, when everything is in one place, then it works. Maybe it's spring issue, maybe maven, don't know yet - will figure out. Thanks for your all help!

Comment: Looks like I found the issue. Probably Queue with the same name had been created twice. First in initialisation of my config: in server.createQueue(new QueueConfiguration(QUEUE_NAME)) != null     then in code above: session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME); When removed first fragment, then everything is fine

Comment: Problem reproduced: https://gist.github.com/wojciech-piotrowiak/77cccb00eaa6c40f5e9a69af84eb0eee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code is subtle but important. When configuring the broker you're creating a queue like so:

```java
...
final String QUEUE_NAME = "myQueue";
...
jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().createQueue(new QueueConfiguration(QUEUE_NAME))
...
```

This is perfectly valid in and of itself, but for this use-case involving a JMS queue it's important to note that this will result in an address named `myQueue` and a **multicast** queue named `myQueue` since the default routing type is MULTICAST and you didn't specify any routing type on your `QueueConfiguration`. This is *not* the kind of configuration you want for a JMS queue. You want an address and an ANYCAST queue of the same name (i.e. `myQueue` in this case) as noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html). Therefore, you should use:

```java
...
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.RoutingType;
...
jmsServer.getActiveMQServer().createQueue(new QueueConfiguration(QUEUE_NAME).setRoutingType(RoutingType.ANYCAST))
```

When you use the multicast queue the message sent by the JMS client will not actually be routed because it is sent with the anycast routing type.

Another option would be to *not create* the queue explicitly at all and allow it to be auto-created.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Am I right that previous code responsible for queue creation: jmsServer.getJMSServerManager().createQueue(true, queueName, null, true, queueName) sets ANYCAST routing which makes difference?  Second question: is there any difference between creating queue using server vs using session? Both will be durable? At this moment my code does not create queue explicity and it's autocreated from session on init, everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, the `createQueue` methods of `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.JMSServerManager` use anycast. There's no real difference in the queue created with the code I pasted vs. the JMS session. The real difference is related to how you want to manage your resources (e.g. create them all statically and disable auto-create or enable auto-create and don't create anything statically).